# Inaccurate results in search catalog

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

I'm trying to catalogSearch products by category but it's giving me inaccurate results like products that are not in the category, i have set to "No" searchable description ,reindex catalog search index and search type to "Fulltext""

Is there any other options of search catalog in magento ?

Comment: How's the search query string looks like?

Comment: Let's say in category books : " the black book", it returns all the books containing one of those not the exact book.

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: Yes, i have reindexed again and it was solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that product name is used in search and try to switch to Combine Search, a reindex (may be a full one) is necessary after such change. 
Here you can find an explanation on [how the magento search works](http://sherodesigns.com/how-the-magento-search-works/).